# How to get all the guilds a user is the owner of?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to get the list of servers I am the owner of.
Is there a function like this:

```
guilds = client.get_guild(id).owner.ownedguilds()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
guilds = []
user = bot.get_user(your_id)
for guild in user.mutual_guilds: #mutual guilds returns the guilds that you and bot is already in
  if guild.owner.id == user.id: #checking owner is you
    guilds.append(guild)
```

Comment: How to get the guilds that the bot is not a member of?

Comment: Bots aren't allowed to get guilds, members, channels if they are not in them.

Comment: please close this question with voting me or add to title "[closed]".